# Predicting from an already fitted model in an R package

Tags: r, package

I'm working on an R package where I need to call `predict.lm` on a model I've already fit. I've saved the linear model as a file which I can put in the data folder of the package. I'm worried about slowing things down if I load the model every time the function is called. The function that uses this model is the meat of the package and gets called on every iteration of a simulation, so I'd prefer to read the saved model once when the package is loaded. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Looking back, I could have easily included the model as part of the lazy loaded package `data` and just referenced `mypackage::mymodel` whenever I needed it. Four years later I'm not even sure what I was trying to do that was different from that (obvious) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just save the coefficients and then "predict" with them?

```
c.vec <- coef(fit)  # Intercept + terms
Yhat <- c.vec * c(1, data.vec)
```

Comment: It's a bit of a pain because there are quite a few interaction terms which I'd have then have to make sure get coded correctly into the `c.vec`. Definitely a good option though.

Comment: The usual path to success in more complex problems is construction of an example that contains only as much detail as needed. If your models involve interactions among factors and numeric classed variables, then present a a minimal example.